# "noise" and "noise-reduction" tags : do we need both?

Tags: discussion, tags

See [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/32298/why-are-light-aircraft-engines-so-noisy) for example. I cannot imagine an example where "noise" is discussed but it is not about noise reduction. (noise enhancement???)

I suggest we keep the shorter one, [noise](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noise), and make the other synonym.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking on the [noise](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noise) tag you can get some examples of questions about noise but no reduction:

[How does the noise of a 2-to-4-seat helicopter compare with that of a similarly-sized fixed-wing aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/70351/how-does-the-noise-of-a-2-to-4-seat-helicopter-compare-with-that-of-a-similarly)

[Why is a Lockheed MC-130J Commando II creating such a loud droning sound?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/70749/why-is-a-lockheed-mc-130j-commando-ii-creating-such-a-loud-droning-sound)

[What causes the nose landing gear knocking noise on a Boeing 777 while taxiing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/60809/what-causes-the-nose-landing-gear-knocking-noise-on-a-boeing-777-while-taxiing)

[Can ADS-B used for voice communications?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65670/can-ads-b-used-for-voice-communications)

So to me it is not clearly a synonym of [noise-reduction](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noise-reduction) given the current state of things.